# Getting day differences between array of dates in pyspark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark

I have column that is an array of ordered dates in a Pyspark dataframe:

```
dates:array
     element:timestamp
```

[ "2012-02-13T00:00:00.000+0000", "2015-01-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2018-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000"]

I would like to create a new column that contains the date differences between each of these. So in the example, the desired output would be:

[1081, 1277, 731]

And the new column would be:

```
date_diffs:array
  element: integer
```

Thanks in advance for helping me come up with the code to produce this.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

tt = [ "2012-02-13T00:00:00.000+0000", "2015-01-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2018-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000"]
todate = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[:10],'%Y-%m-%d')
dd = [todate(tt[ii])-todate(tt[ii-1]) for ii in range(1, len(tt))]
print(dd)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for a soln that incorporated a new withColumn. See my edits above in the og question

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType, ArrayType, IntegerType

datalist = [
    ["2012-02-13T00:00:00.000+0000", "2015-01-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2018-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000", "2020-07-29T00:00:00.000+0000"],
    ["2012-02-13T00:00:00.000+0000", "2015-01-30T00:00:00.000+0000", "2018-07-31T00:00:00.000+0000", "2020-08-01T00:00:00.000+0000"],
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(datalist, ['t1', 't2', 't3', 't4'])
for c in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c, df[c].cast(TimestampType()))

_udf = F.udf(lambda x1, x2, x3, x4: [(x2-x1).days, (x3-x2).days, (x4-x3).days], ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df = df.withColumn('date_diffs', _udf(df['t1'], df['t2'], df['t3'], df['t4']))

df.show()
```

result:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|                 t1|                 t2|                 t3|                 t4|       date_diffs|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
|2012-02-13 09:00:00|2015-01-29 09:00:00|2018-07-29 09:00:00|2020-07-29 09:00:00|[1081, 1277, 731]|
|2012-02-13 09:00:00|2015-01-30 09:00:00|2018-07-31 09:00:00|2020-08-01 09:00:00|[1082, 1278, 732]|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your sample input, we can use [`zip_with`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.zip_with.html#pyspark-sql-functions-zip-with) function in the following way.

- create an array column that has all timestamps from first to last but second
- create an array column that has all timestamps from second to last

Use the aforementioned in `zip_with` and subtract.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('ts_remove_last', func.expr('slice(ts_arr, 1, size(ts_arr)-1)')). \
    withColumn('ts_remove_frst', func.expr('slice(ts_arr, 2, size(ts_arr))')). \
    withColumn('ts_diff',
               func.expr('zip_with(ts_remove_last, ts_remove_frst, (x, y) -> datediff(y, x))')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
# |id |ts_arr                                                                              |ts_remove_last                                                 |ts_remove_frst                                                 |ts_diff          |
# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
# |1  |[2012-02-13 00:00:00, 2015-01-29 00:00:00, 2018-07-29 00:00:00, 2020-07-29 00:00:00]|[2012-02-13 00:00:00, 2015-01-29 00:00:00, 2018-07-29 00:00:00]|[2015-01-29 00:00:00, 2018-07-29 00:00:00, 2020-07-29 00:00:00]|[1081, 1277, 731]|
# +---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```